# Zabbix multiple agent instances of different versions

Tags: windows, process, zabbix

I was wondering if there is anyway that different versions of zabbix agent can runned on a windows server.

The documentation mentions something about multiple "intances" but doesnt look like this is creating any more services.

I've tried running version 3.2 alongside 2.4 on a test server but only one service can run at a time, if I try and start service 2, I'll get:

[image]

As you can see from the screen shoot the service have different names and calling diferent version of the executable.

Both services run, just not at the same time.

Comment: If you stop the 2.4 agent, does the 3.2 one start up?

Comment: Yes, actually I thought I stated that clearly on my question, I'm going to edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry for missing that. What about the agent configuration, have you configured separate listening port and anything else that could conflict? If you try to start both agents manually from the commandline, passing the configuration file, do you see a helpful error message?

Comment: Is never going to work, as afther I install Zabbix I change the name of the service becuase if not it wont install the other version. so when try to run it doesn't find the service as the name has changed. I was looking for a way to choose the name of the service during install, but everything indicates it's hardcoded, this is what I get tho https://ibb.co/kFp9gF

Comment: Use the sc create command to add the second zabbix version. [See_here](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino -  Thanks for that, I gave it a go but it still no luck they both run but not at the same time. Same error

Comment: Please show the exact commands used to add both versions as services.

Comment: `SC CREATE "Zabbix2.4" Displayname= "Zabbix2.4" binpath= "\"C:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd_2_4.exe\" \"--config c:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd_2_4.win.conf\"" start= auto`
**AND**
`SC CREATE "Zabbix3.2" Displayname= "Zabbix3.2" binpath= "\"C:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd_3_2.exe\" \"--config c:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd_3_2.win.conf\"" start= auto`

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple agents on the same ListenPort. Use different ports per agent instance.